# why doesn't placement of floating-ui work?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, popper.js

I've read floating-ui doc but there are some methods that I really cant understand such as `getElementRects`, `getClippingRect` and `getDimensions`, I tried to learn then by trail and error but I still haven't figured them out how to work with them, here is my snippet code and its placement just doesn't work.

```
this._cleanup = autoUpdate(referenceEl, this.floatingEl, () => {
  computePosition(referenceEl, this.floatingEl, {
    strategy: 'absolute',
    middleware: [autoPlacement()],
    placement: 'bottom-start',
    platform: {
      getElementRects: () =>
        Promise.resolve({
          reference: { width: 0, height: 0, x: 0, y: 0 },
          floating: { width: 0, height: 0, x: 0, y: 0 }
        }),
      getClippingRect: () => ({ x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0 }),
      getDimensions: (element) => {
        console.log({ element });

        return { width: 0, height: 0 };
      }
    }
  }).then(({ x, y }) => {
    Object.assign(this.floatingEl.style, {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: `${x}px`,
      top: `${y}px`
    });
  });
});
```

As you can see the floating element is on top end of the input element.

[image]

I guess the `computePosition` method is not configured properly moreover I haven't found any example for vanilla js floating-ui til now.

PS: I can't remove `getElementRects`, `getClippingRect` and `getDimensions` because they are required and if I ignore them with `//@ts-ignore` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide the `platform` object yourself, it's for advanced use cases and is entirely optional as the `@floating-ui/dom` library already provides those methods for you. If you've installed `@floating-ui/core`, uninstall it and install `@floating-ui/dom` instead.

Then, you can remove the `platform` property from the options to use the default/recommended platform and it will work.